# iterating through a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of sequences l (many 1000's of sequences): `l = [ABCD,AABA,...]`.
I also have a file `f` with many 4 letter sequences (around a million of them). I want to choose the closest string in `l` for every sequence in `f` up to a Hamming distance of atmost 2, and update the counter `good_count`. I wrote the following code for this but it is very slow. I was wondering if it can be done faster.

```
def hamming(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
            raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")  
    return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))

f = open("input.txt","r")

l = [ABCD,AABA,...]

good_count = 0
for s in f:
     x = f.readline()
     dist_array = []
     for ll in l:
        dist = hamming(x,ll)
        dist_array.append(dist)
     min_dist = min(dist_array)
     if min_dist <= 2:
        good_count += 1
print good_count
```

It works fast if `l` and `f` are small but takes too long for large `l` and `f`. Please suggest a quicker solution.

Comment: I'd suggest you parse that file first and save elements in a list, then apply `filter` and then return the size of the list.

Comment: a little advice , you can calculate min during iteration and you don't need another loop for `min(dist_array)`

Comment: Another advice  - if the distance is 0, you can break the loop.

Comment: There are only ~457k possible 4 letter sequences. You may also want to consider eliminating the duplicates before you check each one. (Assuming we're limited to the 26 English letters)

Comment: @khachik in fact if the distance in <= 2 you can break the loop, since we never use `ll` in anything!

Comment: What is that `x = f.readline()` for? Do you want to skip every other line (those stored in `s` but never used)?

Comment: If all that's needed is the count, maybe use a data structure that can be put into a `set` to represent the elements of `I`? Basically blow out each pattern into eg `AB??`, `A?C?`, `A??D`, `?BC?`, `?B?D`, `??CD`, and store all the valid "if it matches this it is at most 2 away from a valid sequence" representations in a set. Then expand each line into all 6 of its  corresponding elements and check for set membership. Six set membership tests should be significantly faster than iterating through a list of many thousands of sequences even on a big set.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper do you mind if I add that to my answer? It's a great suggestion for large `f` datasets

Comment: If you do need the closest match for something (not shown in the above code) you could try doing a set of all exact patterns, one of all distance one patterns, and all distance two patterns. That's still only 11 things to check for, but at some point the sets start to take noticeable memory.

Comment: @AdamSmith - feel free.

Answer (score 2):

Use existing libraries, for instance jellyfish:

```
from jellyfish import hamming_distance
```

Which gives you a C implementation of the hamming distance.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, you're just counting how MANY have matches with a hamming distance < 2? That can be done much quicker.

```
total_count = 0

for line in f:
    # skip the s = f.readline() since that's what `line` is in this
    line = line.strip()  # just in case
    for ll in l:
        if hamming(line, ll) <= 2:
            total_count += 1
            break  # skip the rest of the ll in l loop
    # and then you don't need any processing afterwards either.
```

Note that most of your code time will be spent on the line:

```
        if hamming(line, ll) <= 2:
```

So any way you can improve that algorithm will GREATLY improve your overall script speed. Boud's answer extols the virtues of `jellyfish`'s `hamming_distance` function, but without any personal experience I can't recommend it myself. However his advice to use a faster implementation of hamming distance is sound!

---

Peter DeGlopper suggests blowing the `l` list into six different sets of "Two or less hamming distance" matches. That is, a group of sets that contain all the possible pairs that could have two or less hamming distance.  This might look like:

```
# hamming_sets is [ {AB??}, {A?C?}, {A??D}, {?BC?}, {?B?D}, {??CD} ]
hamming_sets = [ set(), set(), set(), set(), set(), set() ]

for ll in l:
    # this should take the lion's share of time in your program
    hamming_sets[0].add(l[0] + l[1])
    hamming_sets[0].add(l[0] + l[2])
    hamming_sets[0].add(l[0] + l[3])
    hamming_sets[0].add(l[1] + l[2])
    hamming_sets[0].add(l[1] + l[3])
    hamming_sets[0].add(l[2] + l[3])

total_count = 0

for line in f:
    # and this should be fast, even if `f` is large
    line = line.strip()
    if line[0]+line[1] in hamming_sets[0] or \
       line[0]+line[2] in hamming_sets[1] or \
       line[0]+line[3] in hamming_sets[2] or \
       line[1]+line[2] in hamming_sets[3] or \
       line[1]+line[3] in hamming_sets[4] or \
       line[2]+line[3] in hamming_sets[5]:
        total_count += 1
```

You could possibly gain readability by making `hamming_sets` a dictionary of `transform_function: set_of_results` key value pairs.

```
hamming_sets = {lambda s: s[0]+s[1]: set(),
                lambda s: s[0]+s[2]: set(),
                lambda s: s[0]+s[3]: set(),
                lambda s: s[1]+s[2]: set(),
                lambda s: s[1]+s[3]: set(),
                lambda s: s[2]+s[3]: set()}

for func, set_ in hamming_sets.items():
    for ll in l:
        set_.add(func(ll))

total_count = 0

for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if any(func(line) in set_ for func, set_ in hamming_sets.items()):
        total_count += 1
```

Comment: I want to count the instances when the closest match has Hamming distance of 2. I don't want to over count. For example a string in f can have matches in l with Hamming distance 0,1,2,3,4. I want to take the closest match (in this case Hamming distance 0) and increment the counter once

Comment: Which is exactly what this does -- the `break` in the `if` block stops all further iteration. This is known as "early exit"

Comment: N.B. @Ssank that your code doesn't *as an end result* care about finding the closest match, it only cares if you've found a match with distance <= 2. You'll continue through the whole `l` list until you've found the closest match, but the result doesn't depend on it.

If your intended result DOES depend on finding the closest match in all cases, you should amend your example code to match. Otherwise, this early exit will provide on average a much faster run time

Comment: I think the example code to implement the `hamming_sets` needs to maintain spacing with a placeholder like the `?` in the example - just recording `AB` for pattern `ABCD` would mean that line `CDAB` would look like a match.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper it shouldn't, since we're pulling the same characters out of the test line. The last edit might make that more clear

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper probably not, since it's Python. A two-character array would be smaller than a four-character array in lower-level languages, but I'm sure Python abstracts them to take the same amount of memory regardless, and that's all you're really saving!

Comment: By the by, this is the first time I've had to wonder to myself: "Can I key a dictionary by a function?" Turns out: yes!

Comment: My implementation shows `sys.getsizeof("AB")` as 39, `sys.getsizeof("AB??")` as 41. So the object overhead clearly dominates, but the extra characters make a small difference. Not likely to matter in this case, and different implementations might behave differently.